# Does the TMNT episode 'The Darkness Within' reference a specific H.P. Lovecraft story?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft, cthulhu-mythos, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-2003

There's no mistaking that the TMNT episode [The Darkness Within](http://tmnt.wikia.com/wiki/The_Darkness_Within) pays homage to H.P. Lovecraft.

Is there any specific story the writers are trying to reference? Or is it just the themes?

Answer (score 13):

I am one of the developers and saw your post recently. We used many references from H.P. Lovecraft's works but there is no, one specific book we aimed to predominate the story.

Comment: Ah: turns out the question was actually about an episode of *Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles*, and not your game. (I don’t suppose your game was influenced by the episode, was it?)